# How could I pass parameter to fragment without replace?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm looking for a solution to pass parameters between Fragments without replace. I have 2 fragments, Frag1 and Frag2. Frag1 needed some informations of Frag2 but I can't replace Frag2.

How could send parameters from Frag2 to Frag1 without replace that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a communication channel between the 2 fragments with the help of their host activity and listeners.

The Fragment that has to send the data can use a listener implemented by the host activity, here is how it can be done:

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    ...
    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnArticleSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Send the event and position to the host activity
        mListener.onArticleSelected(position);
    }
}
```

The code for the Activity which hosts 2 fragments, contains the listener implementation which on trigger calls the second hosted fragment.

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements OnArticleSelectedListener{
    ...

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the FragmentA 
        // Do something here to display that article

        FragmentB articleFrag = (FragmentB)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);
        articleFrag.doWhateverWithDataFromFragmentA(position); 
    }
}
```

Final, step the receiver Fragment which gets the data.

```
public static class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    ...
    // This can also have another or the same listener to send data back,
    // in case of the same, I think its better to have 2 different methods
    // to avoid getting in an infinite loop.



    public void doWhateverWithDataFromFragmentA(int position) {
        // Got the data from A!
    }

}
```

*Source/Reference: The whole idea is based in the combination of the two tutorials from android developers:* [*Communicating with the Activity*](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) and [*Communicating with Other Fragments*](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Generally,

This is a helpful way to transfer data on actions or the actions themselves from one fragment to another.

In case you just need to **share data between the fragments** consider keeping data in Host Activity and access them from both fragments. If your data object at host activity is `private MySharedDataObject thisLocalPrivateObject;` then it can be referenced from the fragments with:

```
MySharedDataObject data = ((MyHostActivityName) getActivity()).getSharedData();
```

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using event bus library like greenrobot EventBus. With it, you will be ablt to post a message from one fragment and receive it in another. It is really simple and really powerful at the same time.

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus